# How to format hex string to solidity address?

Tags: addresses, ethers.js, encoding, hex

Say I have a hex string `c4ef705a8a8f2db126b92013b4938230df2158b5` how can I format it as a solidity address using ethers js or another npm package to prepend `0x` and correctly capitalise some of the alphabetical hex characters like so: `0xc4ef705a8a8F2Db126B92013B4938230DF2158b5`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a small investigation the [ethers.utils.getAddress](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/address/) function formats the address as desired.